# Directive in another directive template: how to make it execute?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid

I am trying to declare a directive inside my custom directive template. Note that desired directive should use a field from my directive scope:

```
angular.module('core.directives')
 .directive('containertable', function () { 
    /**
     * Startup function for directive
     */
    function link(scope, element, attr) {
          // ...init of scope.childgridoptions object skipped...
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { data: '='},
        template: "<ng-grid='childgridoptions'></ng-grid>"
    };
}
```

It looks like that ng-grid directive does not get executed when my directive is invoked, despite the fact that I do see template in my page source. Perhaps it needs to be compiled or something?

Comment: Can you use the debugger to check if the ng-grid's link function is being executed? If its template is showing up, seems like it should be. That might provide a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/0NbC9UH7NnChl8emjrYS?p=preview)
with a working example of a directive based on your example

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'data' };
  $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
});

app.directive('mygrid',function(){
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
  }
  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 
      data: '=',
      gridoptions: '='
    },
    template: '<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridoptions"></div>'    
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I initialised childGridOtions not as $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'data' }; but $scope.gridOptions = { data: scope.data }; that was the issue.